# REACTJS JSX re render

Tags: reactjs, render

I want to re-render html in App.js what is triggered by click event.

In first load JSX component `<WaypointList waypoint_is_done={false} App={this}/>` is rendered.

But when i click button then it wont render JSX component `<WaypointList waypoint_is_done={true} App={this}/>` again.

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            content: this.index()//LETS LOAD CONTENT
        };

        this.index = this.index.bind(this);
        this.toggleDoneList = this.toggleDoneList.bind(this);
    };

    index() {

        return <WaypointList waypoint_is_done={false} App={this}/>;
    };
    //SET NEW RENDERER ONCLICK
    toggleDoneList(){

        console.log('click');
        this.setState({
            content: <WaypointList waypoint_is_done={true} App={this}/>
            //content: <div>see</div>
        });
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.content);
        return this.state.content;
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

First time it fire WaypointList class, but when i click button "object-done-listing" then not
It calls the App.toggleDoneList and App.render is also fired and it get correct JSX component but does not fire WaypointList class again

```
class WaypointList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.App = props.App;
        this.state = {
            content: this.index(props)
        };

        this.index = this.index.bind(this);
    };

    index(props) {

        let rows = logistic_route_sheet_waypoint_rows;

        if (rows.length > 0) {

            return (
                <div className="map-listing">
                    <div className="object-done-listing noselect btn btn-success"
                         onClick={() => this.App.toggleDoneList()}>
                        <i className="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
        return (null);
    };

    render() {

        return this.state.content;
    };
}
```

It works if i set

```
this.setState({
    content: <div>see</div>
});
```

but not with

```
this.setState({
    content: <WaypointList waypoint_is_done={true} App={this}/>
});
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to re-renderer the class

i made "CustomEvent" "reRenderer" and i call re_renderer function outside of react.